# Steven Weinberg says $L$ is the fundamental EM wavelength in a cubical cavity $L^3;$ not the typically asserted $2L.$

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, resonance, waveguide, harmonics

This is from Steven Weinberg's Lectures on Quantum Mechanics, 2nd Ed., page 2:

> For instance, for a cubical box of width $L,$ whatever boundary condition is satisfied on one face of the box must be satisfied on the opposite face, so the phase of the radiation field must change by an integer multiple of $2\pi$ in a distance $L.$

Wavelength $\lambda$
is the distance over which the phase changes by $2\pi$.  So according to Weinberg the longest resonant wavelength in the cavity is $\lambda=L.$ The value found elsewhere for the fundamental wavelength is $\lambda=2L.$

For example, setting $n_{1}=1,n_{2}=n_{3}=0,$ in the expression

$$n_{1}^{2}+n_{2}^{2}+n_{3}^{2}=\frac{4L^{2}}{\lambda^{2}}$$

found here: [Electromagnetic Waves in a Cubical Cavity](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/rayj.html#c2%22), gives $\lambda=2L.$  Which is what I would expect.  This is also consistent with other reputable sources.

**Is Weinberg's value correct?  If so, why is it twice what is typically asserted?**

I'm guessing it has to do with how he states the boundary conditions.  It is possible that Weinberg is wrong, but very unlikely.

Comment: It depends on the boundary conditions. In a cubical box the variable can be separated, so each of X, Y, and Z have the maximum length $L$. Withe *zero* boundary conditions at both ends the fundamental wave length is equal to $L$.

Comment: I don't understand what is meant by *zero* boundary conditions.  The link I referenced assumes the waves have zero amplitude at the walls.  That gives a fundamental wave length of $2L$.  Which is consistent with the discussion found here https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_49.html

Comment: I meant the maximum length of the harmonic oscillation is $L$. There may be also $L/2$, $L/3$, etc. They are just not obligatory "full waves", but a "half-wave", etc.

Comment: A zero *amplitude* boundary condition leads to a fundamental wavelength of $2L$.

Comment: No wave can exceed the box length $L$.

Comment: So the other two sources I referenced are wrong, as is this https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=B-W1iFIkFXU ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two sets of counting the number of states, related to the boundary conditions, known as the fixed boundary condition and the periodic boundary condition.

1. The fixed boundary condition requires $f(0) = f(L) = 0$. Therefore
   $$
   f(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}} \sin k x, \,\,\text{   where   } \,\, k = \frac{n\pi}{L}, \text{  with } n = 1, 2, ... 
   $$
   In this scheme, the longest eave length is $\lambda = \frac{2\pi}{k}= \frac{2\pi}{\pi/L} = 2L$. There is a state in very $\Delta k = \frac{\pi}{L}$.
2. The periodic boundary condition require $f(0) = f(L).$
   $$
     f(x) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{L}}e^{ikx} \,\,\text{  where }\,\, k=\frac{2n\pi}{L} \,\, \text{ with } n = ...-2, -1, 1, 2, ...
   $$
   In this scheme, the separation in k-space is twice as that in the fixed boundary, but the compensation comes from the degenerate in $\pm n$, they are now two independent states.

Under this scheme, the longest wave length will be $L$.